# org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.isFallbackPageable

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data

Im developing a REST API with spring-data-rest and I have services collection that run good under spring-data-rest 2.0.2, but when I update its version to 2.1.4.RELEASE or 2.2.0.RC1 it always fails:

Errors of 2.1.4.RELEASE:

```
<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Sun Aug 31 20:49:42 CEST 2014</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).</div><div>Could not write JSON: Detected multiple association links with same relation type! Disambiguate association @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore(value=true) @org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource(description=@org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.Description(value=), path=, exported=false, rel=) @javax.persistence.OneToMany(fetch=LAZY, orphanRemoval=false, cascade=[ALL], mappedBy=person, targetEntity=void) private java.util.Set com.ifbp.portal.model.Person.attributes using @RestResource! (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources["_embedded"]->java.util.UnmodifiableMap["statistics"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Detected multiple association links with same relation type! Disambiguate association @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore(value=true) @org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource(description=@org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.Description(value=), path=, exported=false, rel=) @javax.persistence.OneToMany(fetch=LAZY, orphanRemoval=false, cascade=[ALL], mappedBy=person, targetEntity=void) private java.util.Set com.ifbp.portal.model.Person.attributes using @RestResource! (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources["_embedded"]->java.util.UnmodifiableMap["statistics"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])</div></body></html>
```

Errors of 2.2.0.RC1:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.isFallbackPageable(Lorg/springframework/data/domain/Pageable;)Z
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(DefaultedPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:59)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilter(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Note: In the first case there isn't any exception in the Eclipse console.

Comment: I'm running into this as well - have you come up with a solution or a core issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to put the latest spring-data-commons to your classpath or pom file if you are using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Your application might be pointing to an older version. HTH